# Can't get premake working - gltut demos

Tags: opengl, lua, premake

https://bitbucket.org/alfonse/gltut/downloads

this is the repository for the several tutorials in this online-book

http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut

the author uses [premake](http://industriousone.com/premake) as alternative to cmake, and i have tried every possible command line options but nothing works.

I don't get why the author wants to use the latest tool on earth but i need to solve this and i don't even have a clue about Lua and this tool.

For who wants to help me with this you have to download [this](http://glsdk.sourceforge.net/docs/html/index.html) to actually build the demos and put it in the root folder of your gltut project.

The URL for the mercurial repository is

```
hg clone https://bitbucket.org/alfonse/gltut
```

My OS is Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit.

Comment: "*For who wants to help me with this you have to download this to actually build the demos and put it in the root folder of your gltut project.*" No, you don't. The build instructions do not tell you to download the SDK; it comes *with* the distribution.

Comment: @NicolBolas on my configuration is the only way to get it working and it doesn't comes with my mercurial ceckout, i don't have it in my folder after the checkout.

Comment: You're not supposed to use the Mercurial depot. That's why there's [a distribution to download](https://bitbucket.org/alfonse/gltut/downloads). And that's what the tutorial's build instructions link to for you to download.

Comment: @NicolBolas http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/Building%20the%20Tutorials.html doesn't says exactly what you are saying now, also the link points to the repository and there are no words about this big package for distribution. How i'm supposed to get this information? if this is the real thing that page is really confusing.

Comment: @user827992 it does not link to the repository, it links to a download page on bitbucket where you can find the packaged versions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just noticed that the premake version that comes with Ubuntu 12.04 is the 3.7, just download a newer version from the 4.x branch and the problem is solved.

Comment: Well it's not like premake4 has been released for almost 4 years or anything.

Comment: Just complimenting this information, after downloading `premake4`, you can run it by `./premake4 --file=premake4.lua gmake` in the root folder.